# Replace character + with - in URL users

Tags: php, wordpress, function, url, str-replace

I'm trying to replace `+` in users' names with `-`.
`+` is automatically created when the user name contains a blank space, for example `john taylor` > `john+taylor`

I found these functions, but cannot solve the problem (I'm using a plugin member - ultimate member and no answer from the team support).
Can someone help me?

```
function myUrlEncode($string) {
    $entities = array(' ');
    $replacements = array('-');
    return str_replace($entities, $replacements, urlencode($string));
}

 function str_replace_url($url)
    {
        str_replace(" ", "-", $url);
    }

function try () {
$user  = str_replace(' ', '-', $_GET['user']);
 $user  = mysql_escape_string($user);
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'user'");
}
```

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace + with - in a string like this:

```
function plus_to_minus($user) {
    return str_replace("+", "-", $user);
}

echo plus_to_minus("john+taylor");
// output: john-taylor
echo plus_to_minus("john++taylor");
// output: john--taylor
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `preg_replace` as below.

```
$string = 'I love to work on the PHP development';
$slug = preg_replace('/\s/', '+', $string);
echo $slug;
```

To convert into a function

```
function convertToUrl($string)
{
    return preg_replace('/\s/i', '+', $string);

}

//usage
echo convertToUrl(string);
```

Comment: Im working on it but no results. Do you now what is the exact $ I have to use ? Ref here. [link](https://github.com/ultimatemember/ultimatemember/blob/master/includes/core/class-user.php)

Answer (score -1):

First of all be sure of what you get with `$_GET['user']` with php `var_dump` function, then use `str_replace` according to the string you get:

```
$user = $_GET['user'];

// Verify $user contains +
var_dump($user);

// Replace + with -
$user = str_replace("+", "-", $user);

// Verify $user is correct
var_dump($user);
```

After that call your `try()` function but pay attention to $user variable inside the query string, you omitted the `$`.

```
function try () {
  $user  = mysql_escape_string($user);

  // Here must be $user and not user or you will search for 'user' username
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user'");
}
```

Comment: Grassie. Many thanks to explain me, I’m crap in php, so I paste your 2 strings ‘get user and var dump’ in header and received null. Is it correct? If it is now I need to find the correct “user” in ultimate member plugin, should I substitute both ‘user’ and ‘$user’ in case ex. “um_user” is the mysterious word ?

Comment: ```
$user = $_GET['user'];

// Verify $user contains +
var_dump($user_ID);

// Replace + with -
$user_ID = str_replace("+", "-", $user_ID);

// Verify $user is correct
var_dump($user_ID);
```
 it returns nt(1) string(1) "1" so I think it’s correct..?, but the function doesn’t work.  Users URL doesn’t change, anyway my ref is http://hookr.io/plugins/ultimate-member/1.3.82/files/core-um-short-functions/

Comment: Could you point me the line number of the function you want to modify on that link?

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: [link] (https://github.com/ultimatemember/ultimatemember/blob/master/includes/um-short-functions.php) In line 71 I tried to comment out the value +, but it doesnt work. This is the beginning of that function `function um_clean_user_basename( $value ) {
 $raw_value = $value;
 $value = str_replace( '.', ' ', $value );
 $value = str_replace( '-', ' ', $value );
 $value = str_replace( '+', ' ', $value );` Any ideas?